# Не работает заголовок второго уровня (h2)

Tags: html, css

Почему не работает заголовок второго уровня с классом time (`<h2>` или например, параграф `<p>`).
`<h1 class="time">` который находится в блоке `<div class="head clearfix">`? С `<h1>` все ок.

```css
a {color: #000;}
.head {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.head-logo {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
}

.menu li a {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 23px;
}

.menu li:last-child a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fed136;
}

.wel {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 235px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 75px;
}

.time {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.btn-info {
  width: 240px;
  height: 65px;
  background: rgba(254, 209, 54, 0.7);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-info:hover {
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  background: #d4ad28;
}
```

```html
<div class="head clearfix">
  <!--контент, с фиксированной шириной, центрирован-->
  <div class="head-logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <nav class="main-menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <p class="wel">Let's work together!</p>
  <h1>It’s nice to meet you</h1>
  <h1 class="time">
    <!--time he1e-->
  </h1>
  <!-- h1 - fix -->
  <div class="btn">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input class="btn-info" type="submit" value="tell me more">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите минимальный вопроизводимый пример сниппетом (кнопка `<>`) непосредственно в вопросе. Ссылка на внешний ресурс однажды станет невалидной, и вопрос будет бесполезен для всех.

Comment: А где ваш приведённый CSS?

Comment: как-то сделано все не по-человечески...

Comment: я только учусь. и благодаря конструктивной критике, с пояснением как нужно делать, будет по-человечески...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так все работает , может вы просто изменете цвет ??У вас стоит белый , сменыте на черный!

```css
a {color: #000;}
.head {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.head-logo {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
}

.menu li a {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 23px;
}

.menu li:last-child a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fed136;
}

.wel {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 235px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

h1{  
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: black;
}

 h2 {
  font-size: 75px;
  color:black;
}

.time {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.btn-info {
  width: 240px;
  height: 65px;
  background: rgba(254, 209, 54, 0.7);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-info:hover {
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  background: #d4ad28;
}
```

```html
<div class="head clearfix">
  <!--контент, с фиксированной шириной, центрирован-->
  <div class="head-logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <nav class="main-menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <p class="wel">Let's work together!</p>
  <h1>It’s nice to meet you</h1>
  <h1 class="time">
    <!--time he1e-->
  </h1>
  <!-- h1 - fix -->
  <div class="btn">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input class="btn-info" type="submit" value="tell me more">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: все ок. на фоновом фото не видно черный цвет текста)) спасибо

Comment: Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.